# Kendo Dropdown closes when we click to open it in IE browser

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using Kendo UI v2018.1.221 in my page, whenever I click the dropdown to open it just opens and showing options and closes suddently before I make a selection. It uses serverfiltering as well.
I googled this a lot, but not finding any solutions for this.
sample code:

```
 <table>
<TR>
    <TD ALIGN="left" >Company:</TD>
    <TD ALIGN="left" >
        <select class="form-control" style="width: 80%" name="teamID" id="company">

        </select>
   </TD>
</TR>
```

```
<script>
var dropdown = $("#company").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "name",
            dataValueField: "id",
            filter: 'contains',
            optionLabel: 'Select a Company',
            enable: true,
            scrollable: {
                virtual: true
            },
            virtual: {
                itemHeight: 26
            },
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "#url#"
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 80,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    total: 'recordsTotal',
                    model: {
                        id: 'teamid',
                        fields: {
                            id: {
                                type: 'number'
                            },
                            name: {
                                type: 'string'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }).data("kendoDropDownList");
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have an extra '#' at the start of your definition?

Comment: no that has nothing to do with this issue as it works in chrome, ok i will remove that to avoid confusion.

Comment: i have prepared a dojo for you: http://dojo.telerik.com/iqosIzAw obviously i don't have access to the url you are actually using for the dataset but have modelled what I think you are expecting to get back from the server in the ds variable. does that work for you at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, the above example seems to be NOT working when I pasted it in my code....b/w my page is a bootstrap modal popup window.

Comment: I am using IE11.

Comment: when I replace "kendoDropDownList" with "kendoMultiSelect", it works in IE, but I don't need a multiselect there...seems like kendo bug to me...any thoughts

Comment: further if we break modal window by removing hide class "modal fade", it will work...so this is clearly a kendo bug for singledropdown in IE 11....

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue: kendoDropDownList inside a kendoGrid in a bootstrap modal. I tryed the `appendTo` property with no success

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the focus away from the modal. You could do this on the open event.

```
  open: function(e) {
     $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with the filter. Removing the filter fixed the problem for me.

```js
var dropdown = $("#company").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    // filter: 'contains',
    optionLabel: 'Select a Company',
    enable: true,
    ...
```